# C# error on reading mp3 file by binary reader : The process cannot access the file 'URL\testbinary.mp3' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, binaryreader

hiiii,
      i want to read mp3 file by using binary reader, my code is :

```
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open("Songs/testbinary.mp3", FileMode.Open)))
        {
           int length = (int)br.BaseStream.Length;

            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes(length);

            txtBinary.Text = bytes.ToString();
        }
```

.......
when i execute this code it shows and exception:

> The process cannot access the file 'URL\testbinary.mp3' because it is being used by another process.

where "URL" is my actual file location.

Comment: The exception tells you *exactly* what's wrong.

Comment: No need to open the same file twice. (BTW: use `File.ReadAllBytes` simply)

Comment: thank you ... its my silly mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You open the same file twice (without any sharing option). To read the content of a file as bytes you can use `File.ReadAllBytes`

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("Songs/testbinary.mp3");
```

**BTW: Don't forget `txtBinary.Text = bytes.ToString();` doesn't give you what you think. You will have to use `BitConverter.ToString` or `Convert.ToBase64String`**

Comment: thank you its working properly.... can you help me to convert again this binary text into mp3... or simply i want to play it by buffing

Comment: @Deepak `Convert.FromBase64String`